# Kubernetes service not able to curl itself inside docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes

**Background**
I am testing the Kubernetes setting on `Minikube`. I have two simple services successfully setup and they are backed by simple docker image. Below is an example of my service configuration. I use `NodePort` to expose the service on port 80.

```
# service 1
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service1
spec:
  selector:
    app: service1
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service1-deployment
  labels:
    app: service1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: service1
        image: service1
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
# service 2
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service2
spec:
  selector:
    app: service2
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service2-deployment
  labels:
    app: service2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: service2
        image: service2
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

**Issue**
I use `docker exec -it` to go inside docker container. I can `curl service1` from `service2` container without any issue. However, if I try to `curl service2` from `service2` container, it gets a timeout connection error.

Results from `curl -v service2`

> Rebuilt URL to: service2/
>   Trying 10.101.116.46...
>   TCP_NODELAY set
>   connect to 10.101.116.46 port 80 failed: Connection timed out
>   Failed to connect to service2 port 80: Connection timed out
>   Closing connection 0
>   curl: (7) Failed to connect to service2 port 80: Connection timed out

I guess the DNS records gets resolved correctly, because `10.101.116.46` is the correct IP attached to `service2`. Then what could be the issue cause this problem?

**More Followup Tests**
From my understanding, the Kubernetes service internally maps the port to container port, so in my case it maps service port `80` to pod port `8080`. From `service2` container, I am able to `curl <service2 pod ip>:8080` successfully, but I am not able to `curl <service2 ip>`, which resolves connection time out error. And this happens exactly the same inside the `service1` container that it can access pod but no service. I do not understand is there any internal setting that I miss?

Comment: Can you ping Pod itself using DNS entry in form like: `1-2-3-4.default.pod.cluster.local` as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services)?

Comment: Yes, the pod IP works fine.

Comment: Can you create the other Pod, i.e. `busybox` and try to check service connectivity?

Comment: @mk_sta Can you elaborate more? `busybox` on which pod?

Comment: I mean create separate Pod, i.e. with `busybox` and try to reach `curl <service2 pod ip>:8080` and `curl <service2 ip>` as well as for `service1`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be any of these:

- The pod servicing service2 has a service that is listening on `127.0.0.1` or not listening on `0.0.0.0` (Any IP address)
- service2 has a redirect and your service only listen on port `80`. You would have to enable the other port (possibly `443`) and run `curl` with the `-L` option to follow the link.
- The pod servicing service2 is not even listening on port `80`.

Comment: Yes, it is listening on `0.0.0.0`. It is just a very simple HTTP server comes with Python library. I don't think there is any redirection involved. I can `curl service2` from `service1` container without any issue, so I assume the pod is working fine on port `80`.

Comment: Are both services pointing to the same pods? or which pods are they pointing to?

Comment: They are pointing to different pods. For testing purpose, I just deploy 1 pod for each service.

Comment: Are both services exactly the same and configured exactly the same way?

Comment: Yes, I update the config file in my question. And they are running the exactly the same code snippet. The only things that do not work are `curl service2` inside container `service2` and `curl service1` inside container `service1`.